# How to get child object of the same Model on GraphQL with Lighthouse?

Tags: laravel, graphql, apollo-client, laravel-lighthouse

I have a Model call Task that can depend on another task. So we have a parent Task and a Child task, two objects with the same model.

so I wrote the scheme:

```
type Task {
    id: ID!
    content: JSON!
    task: Task @belongsTo(relation: "task")
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
}
```

And when I check my call task come null, I already tested with tinker and my relation works well. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved creating a Directive:

```php
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Directives;

use Closure;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Values\FieldValue;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\Directive;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\FieldMiddleware;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

class belongsToSameModelDirective implements Directive, FieldMiddleware
{
    public function name(): string
    {
        return 'belongsToSameModel';
    }

    public function handleField(FieldValue $fieldValue, Closure $next): FieldValue
    {

        $previousResolver = $fieldValue->getResolver();

        $wrappedResolver = function ($root, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) use ($previousResolver) {

            $result = $previousResolver($root, $args, $context, $info);

            return $result;
        };

        $fieldValue->setResolver($wrappedResolver);
        return $next($fieldValue);
    }
}
```

it works and actually is more simple that the problem it-self